# How to select which Matlab version to start from shell or Matlab startup?

Tags: matlab, select, startup, versions

I have multiple Matlab versions installed on my PC. To say, R2006b, R2009b, R2010a.
In this particular application I want to start R2009b when I start it from Shell.
Is there any options at the time of startup to select which version to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find which Matlab is started by default, type `path` in the shell (opened by Run->cmd). The first one is the one that is picked if you type `Matlab`.

From the output of `path` you also find where your Matlab versions are located. If you don't want to navigate to the respective folder every time, you can make [console aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682057(VS.85).aspx) for the different versions.

**EDIT**

If you want to solve the problem in a very general sense, I see two possible avenues:

(1) Check the registry for whether Matlab puts something version-specific there that is tied to  the path (or ask TheMathWorks).

(2) Parse path for '\bin\64' (or '\bin\32' if it's a 32-bit system) and check whether these folders contain a file called 'matlab'. As part of the installation routine (if the Matlab versions are not in the factory-default locations), start each Matlab, and run `ver` to find which version it is.

Comment: Thanks Jonas for your reply.
path command returns folder path of the matlab installations. But there is no way to judge where the particular version resides by just analyzing folder path. Usually, matlab versions are stored in 'R2006b', 'R2009b' etc folders but these are just the names of the folder. User can change the folder name, and we cannot get the correct path.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. I don't think there is an easy fix, but I can give you two suggestions

Comment: Thanks again Jonas. Right now I am looking at way (1), to check the registry path. I have come to the conclusion that Mathworks stores the  matlab in the MyComputer->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->MATHWORKS-MATLAB loaction
Again it has following folder for each version.
7.3 : for R2006b
7.9 : for R2009b
7.10: for R2010a
I can check if  '7.9' exist if yes, can read 'MATLABROOT' entry which gives the fullpath of installation.
I need to try this if it can really works.

Comment: I think it should, since matlabroot is a very important parameter.

Comment: The registry method worked, and gave me the desired location of the Matlab R2009b exe.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you simply specify the absolute path to the location of the version you want to run ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem here is that, I want start Matlab from other program and for that I am using shell. I dont know the absolute location of the particular version i.e. R2009b